# Fields for a record in a 'has many' association inside a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, associations, has-many

I have a `Topic` that has many `Post`s. When a topic is created, it creates the first post along with it.

I included the post fields in the form:

```
= form_for @topic do |topic_form|

  # ...

  = topic_form.fields_for @post do |post_fields|
    = post_fields.label :content
    %br/
    = post_fields.text_area :content
    %br/
```

Here's what my `TopicsController` looks like:

```
def new
  @topic = Topic.new
  @post = Post.new
  respond_with @topic
end

def create
  @topic = Topic.create params[:topic]
  @post = @topic.create_post params[:topic][:post]
  respond_with @topic, location: topic_url(@topic)
end
```

I get an `UnknownAttributeError - unknown attribute: post` on the first line of the `create` method. I'm guessing it's because the post hash was included in the topic hash in the request:

```
"topic" => { "title" => "...", "post" => { "content" => "..." } }
```

How can I work around this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your `Topic` model should have a `accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts` in it.
2. Your form should have `= topic_form.fields_for :posts do |post_fields|` instead of `@post`.
3. Neither your `new` nor your `create` methods need the `@post = ....` lines. When you save the `@topic` it will automatically save the new associated post for you.

Here's a great explanation of nested attributes in forms: http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes

Comment: I did as instructed, but I'm still getting the exact same error.